# Is it possible to have a gap between flex boxes while still showing the background?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make space between these sections while still showing the background and I'm not sure how to. I've tried padding and making borders transparent, but that didn't work. I thought about using grid instead, but I want to see if I can do it while still using flex. Thanks

[This is what it looks like with the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N5kg.png)

```css
body{
 font-family:'Helvetica';
 float:center;
 background-color:#606060;
 background-image:url(images/image1.jpg);
 background-size:2048px 1152px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#BF9553;
}

a:hover{
 color:white;
}

a:active{
 color:white;
}

a:visited{
 color:none;
}

#header{
 color:#BF9553;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:60px;
}

#clockbox{
 color:#BF9553;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
 margin-top:-75px;
 padding-bottom:25px;
}

.links{
 border:1px solid #2E2E2E;
 padding:10px;
 list-style-type:none;
 line-height:1.6em;
 align-content:center;
}

.container-1{
 background-color:#404040;
 display:flex;
 width:550px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 justify-content:space-around;
}

#general{
 flex:1;
}

#manga{
 flex:1;
}

#mail{
 flex:1;
}

.container-2{
 background-color:#404040;
 display:flex;
 width:550px;
 margin: 0 auto; 
}

#torrents{
 flex:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Startpage</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div id="header">
   <h1>Hello, Kyle</h1>
  </div>
 <div id="clockbox"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   function GetClock(){
   var d=new Date();
   var nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getFullYear();
   var nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes(),nsec=d.getSeconds();
   if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin;
   if(nsec<=9) nsec="0"+nsec;

   var clocktext=""+ndate+"."+(nmonth+1)+"."+nyear+" "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+"";
   document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=clocktext;
   }

   GetClock();
   setInterval(GetClock,1000);
  </script>

 </div>
 </header>
 <div class="container-1">

  <div id="general" class="links">
   <li><a href="https://duckduckgo.com">duckduckgo</a></li> 
   <li><a href="https://youtube.com/feed/subscriptions">youtube</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://netflix.com/browse">netflix</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://twitch.tv/directory/following">twitch</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://twitter.com">twitter</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://hulu.com">hulu</a></li> 
  </div>

  <div id="manga" class="links">
   <li><a href="https://myanimelist.net">myanimelist</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://mangadex.org/manga/1054/it-s-not-my-fault-that-i-m-not-popular">watamote</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://mangadex.org/manga/4880/jojo-s-bizarre-adventure-part-8-jojolion">jojolion</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://mangadex.org/manga/350/vinland-saga">vinland saga</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://mangakakalot.com/manga/hgj2047065412">goblin slayer</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://mangakakalot.com/manga/goblin_slayer_side_story_year_one">goblin slayer: year one</a></li>
  </div>

  <div id="mail" class="links">
   <li><a href="https://gmail.com">gmail</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://mail.protonmail.com/inbox">protonmail</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://icloud.com">icloud</a></li>

  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container-2">
  <div id="torrents" class="links">
   <li><a href="https://nyaa.si/">nyaa</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://forum.snahp.it/">snahp.it</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://reddit.com/r/megalinks/">megalinks</a></li>
  </div>

  <div>
   
  </div>
  
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to use `margin`

Comment: just tried and it didn't do anything, thanks though

Comment: do you add it to `.links` ?? and please add more explain what section you want to add

Comment: i tried it with .links and all the subdivisions. I want to add space around the all the blocks in the middle, but i want it so you can see the background and not just have space with solid color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `background-color: #404040;` from `class="container-1"` and add `background` and `margin` to `.links`

```css
body{
 font-family:'Helvetica';
 float:center;
 background-color:#606060;
 background-image:url(images/image1.jpg);
 background-size:2048px 1152px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#BF9553;
}

a:hover{
 color:white;
}

a:active{
 color:white;
}

a:visited{
 color:none;
}

#header{
 color:#BF9553;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:60px;
}

#clockbox{
 color:#BF9553;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
 margin-top:-75px;
 padding-bottom:25px;
}

.links{
border: 1px solid #2E2E2E;
padding: 10px;
list-style-type: none;
line-height: 1.6em;
align-content: center;
background-color: #404040;
margin: 3px;
}

.container-1{
 display:flex;
 width:550px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 justify-content:space-around;
}

#general{
 flex:1;
}

#manga{
 flex:1;
}

#mail{
 flex:1;
}

.container-2{
 background-color:#404040;
 display:flex;
 width:550px;
 margin: 0 auto; 
}

#torrents{
 flex:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Startpage</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div id="header">
   <h1>Hello, Kyle</h1>
  </div>
 <div id="clockbox"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   function GetClock(){
   var d=new Date();
   var nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getFullYear();
   var nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes(),nsec=d.getSeconds();
   if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin;
   if(nsec<=9) nsec="0"+nsec;

   var clocktext=""+ndate+"."+(nmonth+1)+"."+nyear+" "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+"";
   document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=clocktext;
   }

   GetClock();
   setInterval(GetClock,1000);
  </script>

 </div>
 </header>
 <div class="container-1">

  <div id="general" class="links">
   <li><a href="https://duckduckgo.com">duckduckgo</a></li> 
   <li><a href="https://youtube.com/feed/subscriptions">youtube</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://netflix.com/browse">netflix</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://twitch.tv/directory/following">twitch</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://twitter.com">twitter</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://hulu.com">hulu</a></li> 
  </div>

  <div id="manga" class="links">
   <li><a href="https://myanimelist.net">myanimelist</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://mangadex.org/manga/1054/it-s-not-my-fault-that-i-m-not-popular">watamote</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://mangadex.org/manga/4880/jojo-s-bizarre-adventure-part-8-jojolion">jojolion</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://mangadex.org/manga/350/vinland-saga">vinland saga</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://mangakakalot.com/manga/hgj2047065412">goblin slayer</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://mangakakalot.com/manga/goblin_slayer_side_story_year_one">goblin slayer: year one</a></li>
  </div>

  <div id="mail" class="links">
   <li><a href="https://gmail.com">gmail</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://mail.protonmail.com/inbox">protonmail</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://icloud.com">icloud</a></li>

  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container-2">
  <div id="torrents" class="links">
   <li><a href="https://nyaa.si/">nyaa</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://forum.snahp.it/">snahp.it</a></li>
   <li><a href="https://reddit.com/r/megalinks/">megalinks</a></li>
  </div>

  <div>
   
  </div>
  
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```